# How can I build Python CFFI modules during development?

Tags: python, python-cffi

What are best practices for building CFFI modules during development?

Right now I'm using a Makefile:

```
mylib/_ffi.so: my_lib/build_ffi.py
    python $<
```

And then to test I can use:

```
$ make && python test.py
```

But this seems suboptimal. Is there a better way of building CFFI modules during development?

Comment: You could say ``if os.system("make") != 0: raise Exception`` in your ``test.py``

Answer (score 1):

If the project is using setuptools, `python setup.py develop` appears to build the library in-place:

```
$ python setup.py develop
...
Finished processing dependencies for my-lib==0.1
$ ls my_lib/
_ffi.so
...
```

But it doesn't seem like there is a `make clean` equivilent (`setup.py clean` only cleans the `build/` directory), so it isn't quite ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but a suggested improvement on your "suboptimal" solution would be to add the running of pytest into the make file, along the lines of:

```
all: mylib/_ffi.so
    /usr/bin/python test.py
```

which would allow you to just run *make*.